# Using grep to search files provided by find: what is wrong with find . | xargs grep '...'?

Tags: regex, linux, console, find, command

When I use the command:

```
find . | xargs grep '...'
```

I get the wrong matches. I'm trying to search for the string `...` in all files in the current folder.

Comment: then first, you have to learn how to ask the question, properly. technically, there is nothing wrong with it. the question is what you want to do. describe it properly and clearly

Comment: do you mean, what i get as answer?

Comment: Are you sure that grep -R isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @ghostdog74 I applaud your tact.

Comment: @ghostdog74: in the current folder i want to search for the string "..." in all files.

Comment: Included the *regex* tag to reflect the problem

Comment: I definitely just replaced "..." with "blah blah blah" in my head. Oh well.

Comment: @Why are people voting for this to be on serverfault instead of superuser?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As Andy White said, you have to use `fgrep` in order to match for plain `.`, or escape the dots.

So you have to write (`-type f` is to only have the files : you obviously don't want the directories.) :

```
find . -type f | xargs fgrep '...'
```

or if you still want to use grep :

```
find . -type f | xargs grep '\.\.\.'
```

And if you only want the **current** directory and not its subdirs :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs fgrep '...'
```

Comment: @Hasturkun: Yes. I just have the tendency to prefer different command names than extra options (like using `gunzip` instead of `gzip -d`). Just a matter of taste usually.

Comment: It should be noted that `fgrep` and `egrep` have been [deprecated from the POSIX standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383454/109628). Also, using `grep` thoroughly, one should be used to using options anyway. Nevertheless, it still remains subjective what to use.

Answer (score 7):

'.' matches any character, so you'll be finding all lines that contain 3 or more characters.

You can either escape the dots, like this:

```
find . | xargs grep '\.\.\.'
```

Or you can use fgrep, which does a literal match instead of a regex match:

```
find . | xargs fgrep '...'
```

(Some versions of grep also accept a -F flag which makes them behave like fgrep.)

Answer (score 5):

@OP, if you are looking for files that contain ...,

```
grep -R "\.\.\." *
```

Comment: By far the simplest solution. grep has the recursive file searching built in.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a **filename** that matches, try:

```
find . -name "filename pattern"
```

or

```
find . | grep "filename pattern"
```

If your looking for looking for **files** that match (ie it contains the grep string)

```
find . | xargs grep "string pattern"
```

works fine. or simply:

```
grep "string pattern" -R *
```

Comment: yes, I'm looking for files that contains "..." as string, but:

1. find . | xargs grep "string pattern"

or 

2. grep "string pattern" -R *

doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are literally typing `grep '...'` you'll match just about any string.  I doubt you're actually typing `'...'` for your grep command, but if you are, the `...` will match any three characters.

Please post more info on what you're searching for, and maybe someone can help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Jeremy's answer, you may also want to try

```
find . -type f | xargs grep 'your_pattern'
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'your_pattern' {} +
```

Which is similar to a xargs

I might add : RTFM ! Or in a more polite way : use & abuse of

```
man command
```

!

Comment: More polite? Read The Friendly Manual? How could that be considered impolite? Polite freak. :)

Comment: Man pages are indeed pretty friendly and are looking forward to being read again & again. (You made my day, Jeremy XD)

Comment: The later it gets, the more obnoxious my comments seem to get. I think I'm peaking now. It's all downhill from here.

Comment: I assure you I will not sue you for having called (?) me a freak.

Comment: Of course you won't. Then I'd counter sue for you negligent and distasteful use of acronomic foul language.

Comment: Aaaaaand now we're off-topic. :P

Comment: Back on topic.  When using -exec the command needs to end with a \;

Comment: I tested this command before posting, and it worked well. (Running a shell on OpenSuSE11). Could you explain, please ? ;)